# Use multiple render in single scene using threejs

Tags: three.js

I want to use both render (CanvasRenderer and WebGlRenderer) to render a shape in a common scene. Is there any way to use it?

Comment: Why? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff I have only one reason to use both render. The reason is CanvasRender support lineWidth property for LineBasicMaterial but WebGLRender does not support it ( In windows for ANGLE issue).

Answer (score 0):

this would help?

```
function webglAvailable() {
    try {
        var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
        return !!( window.WebGLRenderingContext && (
            canvas.getContext( 'webgl' ) ||
            canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl' ) )
        );
    } catch ( e ) {
        return false;
    }
}

if ( webglAvailable() ) {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
} else {
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
}
```

[Reference](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/CanvasRenderer)

Comment: This is simply checking the webgl is available or not but my requirement is use both render at the common scene.

Comment: Ah! Ok. You tried to create two functions "render": one for the canvas and the other for WebGL and where you want to call each of them you make the call at a "surrender". Or tries to create two "div", one with "render" canvas and the other with WebGL.

But I'm not sure if it would work. Only suggestions. * __ *

Comment: Thanx for your suggestions. I just wanted CanvasRender for creating outline of the shape using EdgesHelper and for draw full or complete shape I want to use WebGLRender. Problem is that everything is happen in the same scene not different scene.

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced anyone would really want to do this...but going to answer the question asked:

1. use `CanvasRenderer` to render your lines at desired width
2. create a `THREE.Texture` from that canvas
3. apply that texture to a screen-sized quad in your `WebGLRenderer`
4. add the rest of your scene
5. write a custom fragment shader to combine the canvas texture with the rest of the scene as desired